# ECS Sonarqube(elasticsearch) - failed to obtain node locks

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I have set up a sonarqube community edition in aws ecs with ec2 as compatibility. I mounted the sonar extension and elasticsearch data folders to efs access points. It was running smoothly until another ecs sonarqube task scaled up but failed with the following issue and I assume its an elasticsearch efs issue.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [/opt/sonarqube/data/es8]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started on the same data path?`

I have set my efs access point with
Posix user=1000:1000
Creation info=1000:1000(0750)

What can be done about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The free open-source version of SonarQube does not support running more than one instance at a time. Also, running the embedded Elasticsearch server only works with a single instance at a time. So to scale SonarQube beyond a single node, you have to use one of the paid versions of SonarQube, and you also need to run Elasticsearch externally, outside of the container. The Data Center edition of SonarQube is actually [the only version](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/sonarqube/downloads/) that lists "Horizontal Scalability" as a supported feature.

If you just want to run a single instance in ECS, and be able to do deployments without running into this error, then you could set Desired Count to `1`, disable auto-scaling, and set the ECS Deployment Maximum Percent to `100`, and the Deployment Minimum Healthy Percent to `0`. This will cause some down-time during deployments, but it's the only way to avoid the locking issues that occur when you run multiple instances of SonarQube.

Comment: Yes, you were right. Thank you for your kind information. I have made a configuration such that ec2 instance is t3.medium were sonarqube running with 1cpu, 2gb ram and RDS with db.t3.micro. Will these be sufficient for sonarqube to run in ecs?

Comment: That depends entirely on the number of projects you have configured, and the size of those projects.